# Glitch with NextAuth session NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I implemented NextAuth in my NextJS 13 app, but when I reload the page, and session hasn't been fetched yet, the data returns as `undefined` first and then after a few attempts the actual data(session) is getting returned. As result, I see the glitch on UI: `Not signed in/ Signed in as ...`

```
export default function RootLayout({ children, session }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <Header />
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Auth page:

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if(session) {
    return <>
      Signed in as {session.user.email} <br/>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  }
  return <>
    Not signed in <br/>
    <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
  </>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As data is not avaialble, session will be `undefined`. so you need to use the status and see whether data is fetched or not. `useSession()` hook returns the status for you.

If you want to have a seamless experience in a client-side implementation. you can do as below.

```js
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  
  // Note: This is not mandatory. Use only if you want to show some kind of loading until you get the data
  if (status === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
   return <>
    Not signed in <br/>
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  }

  return <>
      Signed in as {session.user.email} <br/>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
   </>
  
}
```

if you need to implement this on the server-side, the approach will be this.

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]"


export default function Component() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (typeof window === "undefined") return null
  
  if(session) {
    return <>
      Signed in as {session.user.email} <br/>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  }
  
  return <>
    Not signed in <br/>
    <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
  </>
  
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: await getServerSession(
        context.req,
        context.res,
        authOptions
      ),
    },
  }
}
```